# Multiple dev folders for the same Firebase Cloud Functions account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is is possible to have different developing folders to deploy different Firebase Cloud Functions to the same Firebase account?

Let's say I have 2 folders that were created using `firebase init` from the same Firebase account:

```
dev1 //This folder will deploy function foo()
|____ functions
      |____ src
      |     |____ index.js
      |     |____ environment.js
      | ...


dev2 //This folder will deploy function bar()
|____ functions
      |____ src
      |     |____ index.js //Completely different from dev1/index.js but same file name
      |     |____ environment.js //Completely different from dev1/environment.js but same file name
      | ...
```

If I go inside `dev1` and run `firebase deploy`, I will deploy the `foo()` function.

Then, I go inside `dev2` and also run `firebase deploy`. What will happen? Will the content from `dev2` overwrite `dev1`'s from Google server, or will I be able to just maintain 2 separate, independent folders for the development of the same Firebase account's Firebase Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform a `firebase deploy` from dev2, the CLI will ask you if want to delete function foo :

`Would you like to proceed with deletion? Selecting no will continue the rest of the deployments. (y/N)`

Answering no (N) will not touch functions from the dev1.

A other way you could do would be to use `firebase deploy -only function:foo` from the dev 1 folder and `firebase deploy -only function:bar` from dev2

Since Firebase CLI tools 3.8.0, you can deplow multiple functions by naming them :
`firebase deploy --only functions:func1,functions:func2`

Comment: Thank you for your respond. If I choose not to delete exising `foo()` from the server when doing `firebase deploy` in `dev2`, will it still happen? Also, what are the commands for `--only functions` with more than 1 function name?

Comment: I just updated my answer to respond to that comment.